# With a given list how can I make this searching function return the value instead of it's generator object

Tags: python, list, search, sublist

I have a list that looks like this:

> [['1', ' H ', ' Hydrogen', ' 1.00794(4)', 'FFFFFF', '1s1 ', '2.2', '37', '', '120', '1312', '-73', '-1, 1', 'gas', 'diatomic', '14', '20', '0.0000899', 'nonmetal', '1766'], ['2', ' He ', ' Helium', ' 4.002602(2)', 'D9FFFF', '1s2 ', '', '32', '', '140', '2372', '0', '', 'gas', 'atomic', '', '4', '0.0001785', 'noble gas', '1868'], etc...]

that goes all the way down the periodic table. I also have a function (which is within a class, hence the self.) that is supposed to print a single sublist (one per element) which looks like this:

```
def get_element_data(self, identifier):
    if type(identifier) == int:
        if self.check_atomic_number_exists(identifier):
            return self.parsed_data[identifier - 1]
    if type(identifier) == str:
        if len(identifier) <= 2:
            print("passed in symbol")
            return (element for element in self.parsed_data if identifier == 
                   element[1])
        if len(identifier) > 2:
            print("passed in name")
            return (element for element in self.parsed_data if identifier == 
                    element[2])

parsing_object.get_element_data("Hydrogen")
```

but if I run this it returns a generator object instead of the sublist. How can I make it return the sublist? Also, it works fine if I search by atomic number.

Comment: You are *explicitely* returning generator expressions: `(element for element in self.parsed_data if identifier == 
                    element[2])` Perhaps try using a list-comprehension instead?

Comment: You can try using `next` to find the first element, either returning a default value if not found, or throwing a new, more appropriate, error.

Comment: @Artyer do you mean return next(element for...) because if I do that i get a stop iteration error

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh okay. I'm rather new to this. could you show me what that would look like?

Comment: For an equivalent list comprehension, use square-brackets: `[element for element in self.parsed_data if identifier == element[2]]` I don't know why you are using more advanced constructs like generator expressions if you are new. Learn to walk before you run.

Answer (score 1):

Have it return a list instead.

```
return list(element for ...)
```

...

```
return [element for ...]
```

Or even a tuple if that's what you need.

```
return tuple(element for ...)
```

Comment: Every time you use `list(<genexp>)` a baby python dies.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning this:
`(element for element in self.parsed_data if identifier == element[2])`
which is in fact a generator. I do not know short python that well so I'm not sure if i fully understand your code but I think this is what you want to do:

```
foreach(element in elements):
     if identifier == element[2]:
        return element
```

If you want it to behave like a generator you shouldn't use `return`, you should use `yield`.
This makes you able to do:

```
foreach(value in generator()):
  print value
```

so for you it would be

```
foreach(element in elements):
     if identifier == element[2]:
        yield element
```